# Centering <text> element within <svg>

Tags: svg, text

I have a piece of text I'm showing:

```
    <div id="fixed-target" style="display:block; margin:0 auto; width:100%; height:103px; border:0px solid #000; overflow-x:auto; ">
      <svg width="654" height="83"> 
           <rect id="rect1" x="20" y="59" width="100%" height="83px" fill="transparent" stroke="transparent"></rect>       
                <text text-anchor="start" x="150" y="59" font-family="Abbey" font-size="60px" 
 style="font:bold 80px Arial; color:#fff; fill:rgb(0,0,0);">
           <tspan text-anchor="start" dy="15">Some test text</tspan>
         </text>                          
      </svg>      
    </div>
```

and I know that to get the line to be centered horizontally, I have to increase the "x" parameter of the text element.  But how do I compute what the value should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use text-anchor="middle" and x="50%" to centre the text.

```html
    <div id="fixed-target" style="display:block; margin:0 auto; width:100%; height:103px; border:0px solid #000; overflow-x:auto; ">
      <svg width="654" height="83"> 
                <text text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="59" font-family="Abbey" font-size="60px" 
 style="font:bold 80px Arial; color:#fff; fill:rgb(0,0,0);">
           <tspan dy="15">Some test text</tspan>
         </text>                          
      </svg>      
    </div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly with a single line of text.  But if there are two blocks (copy and paste your block, and make the string in `tspan` longer), the second one is cut off.  How do you handle multiple blocks?

Comment: Feel free to ask another question, make sure your question markup covers that case.

Comment: Absolutely right.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49481269/centering-multiple-blocks-of-svg-elements