# Centering multiple blocks of <svg> elements

Tags: svg, text

If I have two stacked blocks of `text` within `svg`, with the second being larger, the second one gets cut off.

```
    <div id="fixed-target" style="display:block; margin:0 auto; width:100%; height:103px; border:0px solid #000; overflow-x:auto; ">
      <svg width="654" height="83"> 
                <text text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="59" font-family="Abbey" font-size="60px" 
 style="font:bold 80px Arial; color:#fff; fill:rgb(0,0,0);">
           <tspan dy="15">Some test text</tspan>
         </text>                          
      </svg>      
    </div>
    <div id="fixed-target" style="display:block; margin:0 auto; width:100%; height:103px; border:0px solid #000; overflow-x:auto; ">
      <svg width="654" height="83"> 
                <text text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="59" font-family="Abbey" font-size="60px" 
 style="font:bold 80px Arial; color:#fff; fill:rgb(0,0,0);">
           <tspan dy="15">A very very very long block of test text</tspan>
         </text>                          
      </svg>      
    </div>
```

How can I mark this up so the longer one is not cut off?

Comment: Absolutely right - I think just using `width="100%"` is the way to go here. Please make your comment an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've basically got 3 options here

1. Increase the width of the `<svg>` element. You could make it 100% which would be the size of the `<svg>` element's container.
2. Make the font smaller so the text fits in the `<svg>` element
3. Use more `<tspan>` elements to display the text over multiple lines

I've just made the second `<svg>` element arbitrarily wider below.

```html
    <div id="fixed-target" style="display:block; margin:0 auto; width:100%; height:103px; border:0px solid #000; overflow-x:auto; ">
      <svg width="654" height="83"> 
                <text text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="59" font-family="Abbey" font-size="60px" 
 style="font:bold 80px Arial; color:#fff; fill:rgb(0,0,0);">
           <tspan dy="15">Some test text</tspan>
         </text>                          
      </svg>      
    </div>
    <div id="fixed-target" style="display:block; margin:0 auto; width:100%; height:103px; border:0px solid #000; overflow-x:auto; ">
      <svg width="1554" height="83"> 
                <text text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="59" font-family="Abbey" font-size="60px" 
 style="font:bold 80px Arial; color:#fff; fill:rgb(0,0,0);">
           <tspan dy="15">A very very very long block of test text</tspan>
         </text>                          
      </svg>      
    </div>
```